# Menu hiding when outside 'div' element is clicked

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I am creating a simple dashboard in ionic that consists of a toolbar at the top and a collapsible menu (navigation bar)on the left side. The menu is toggled by the menu button in the toolbar, but clicking the standalone 'div' component is also causing the menu to hide.

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-menu type="push" menuId="nav-menu">
      // create menu items
    </ion-menu>
    <div main>
        hello world
    </div>
</ion-content>


I expect the menu to remain open/unchanged when clicking on the hello world.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the normal behaviour and not configurable:

- [ionic/menu.tsx at master · ionic-team/ionic](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/core/src/components/menu/menu.tsx#L213)

I think you should maybe explore split-pane if you want to keep the menu open:

- [ion-split-pane - Ionic Documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/split-pane)

But even then I think you will need to add your own toggle button to all the "desktop" menu to be optionally collapsed.

This tutorial shows how to set it up with a menu in Angular:

- [Split Pane in Ionic ← Alligator.io](https://alligator.io/ionic/split-pane/)

And I think this bit is where you would need to add your own toggle code:

```
<ion-split-pane [when]="checkSize()">
  <!-- ... -->
</ion-split-pane>
```

The tutorial is giving you it from  the point of view of size changes, but I think you could wire this into a toggled bool from your own menu button?